# Chrome Rich Notifications not showing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Ok so in my manifest for my Chrome Extension I've permitted notifications, and right now I'm using the webkitNotifications, though I say the Rich Notifications and liked them more so I went forth and figured out how to write them like which arguments are needed and so I tested in the console yet it is not showing up?

```
chrome.notifications.create('report',{
  type:'basic',
  title:'hello world',
  message:'Dance with me please',
  expandedMessage:'Hello thanks for using our app',
  priority:1,
  buttons:[{title:'Follow URL'},{title:'Remind me Later'}],
  isClickable:true
},function(){});
```

Yet I'm not sure if this is all I need for `webkitNotifications` need a `show()` function to actually make it show. Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 1):

`iconUrl` is required for `create` method. http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications#type-NotificationOptions

```
chrome.notifications.create('report',{
  type:'basic',
  title:'hello world',
  iconUrl: 'yourIconUrl',
  message:'Dance with me please',
  expandedMessage:'Hello thanks for using our app',
  priority:1,
  buttons:[{title:'Follow URL'},{title:'Remind me Later'}],
  isClickable:true
},function(){});
```